# How to execute a sql file file.sql with zend framework 1.12?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Php script:

```
   $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
   $file_content = file_get_contents('file.sql', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
   if($file_content!=''){
       $db->query($sql);
   }
```

It works for me if the sql file contains a simple sql query.

My sql file contains a procedure declaration:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC()
BEGIN
    ALTER ...... ;
    DELETE ..... ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If content of your `file.sql` is used as sql query string, it should look like the following(without "delimiters"):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROC()
BEGIN
    ALTER ...... ;
    DELETE ..... ;
END
```

Also, check if a certain procedure doesn't exist in database beforehand:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mysql.proc p WHERE db = 'db_name' 
AND name = 'PROC');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like it won't happen with ZF1.12](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-1694)